# How to call custom directive template url on button click using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to call a html page which is given in the templateUrl of my directive when I click a button, below is my code "hi" should be displayed when I click the "click me" button. Please suggest me how to do this.

sample.html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <button custom-click="">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

sample.js:

```
appRoot.directive('customClick', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.click(function(){
           templateUrl:'/page.html';
          }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Page.html:

```
<div><h4>HI</h4></div>
```

Comment: There's a syntax error inside the click callback. And also, where is your `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 2):

Update: The Snippet has been updated with getting the code from a URL

Adding onto the above answers:

```
appRoot.directive('customClick', function($http, $compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function(){
                    $http.get("/page.html").then(function(resp){
                        $(element).html(resp.data);
                        var fnLink = $compile(element);
                        fnLink($scope);
                    });
                }); 
            }
        }
});
```

P.S: Needs jQuery to run as using some functions like html() which can be bypassed if you dont want to include jQuery